# What kind of lookup is performed by list.index(value)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hashtable, cpython

What does python do behind the scenes when I call:

```
very_big_list.index(value)
```

On a list of strings?

Is it more efficient than this equivalent dictionary lookup?

```
d = {'hello':1, 'dog':2, 'cat':3, ...}
print d['dog']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.index()` loops through the list until it finds an element that is equal (`element == searchterm` is True). A dictionary lookup is *much* more efficient.

In CS terms, `.index()` is of O(n) complexity, dict lookups are O(1). See the [Time Complexity overview](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) on the Python Wiki.

Comment: @luke14free: lists are more compact than a dict. Python dicts are [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and use open addressing.

Comment: yes, my issue is both in term of memory (the list is huge) and of computing time. Probably if dicts can't make it because of memory issues I can try to switch to cython and use ordered lists on which the lookup time should go down to log(n) using bisection.

Comment: Exactly; use a different data structure in that case. Perhaps a [`heapq` structure](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) or a binary tree (easy enough to build yourself) would be more suitable; depends on your exact use case.

Comment: Possibly a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) if there are lots of common prefixs in the keys

Comment: @luke14free: **But** note that the `dict` and `list` structures only need to hold pointers. They are, of themselves, not big. So even a `dict` that holds a million items is *of itself* not a memory hog.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I heard that cpython works under the philosophy "everything is a pointer", but still I guess that a dict will translate into something like an hashed table with tons of hashes which need to be stored into ram, making them therefore a little bit more "heavy" than lists. Is it correct?

Comment: @luke14free: Yes, indeed; the hashes for the keys *are* cached to facilitate resizes. The [python hash implementation source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c) is well commented if you are interested.